# Recuperar todos os eventos usando FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, calendar

Eu preciso recuperar todos os eventos do meu calendário e depois recuperar todos os dias que têm um evento.

Eu já tentei

```
$("#calendar").fullcalendar("getSource");
```

mas iss não funciona

Answer (score 0):

Para capturar todos os eventos, utilize:

```
// Obter array de eventos
var eventos = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
```

Esse comando retornará um array com todos os eventos, e consequentemente dentro de cada evento tem uma data inicio e uma data fim. Você pode percorrer esse array e obter todas as datas inicio de cada evento:

```
// Criar um array para armazenar os dias que tem evento
var dias = [];

// Percorrer array de eventos armazenando os dias que ainda não estão no array
eventos.forEach(function(evento){
    var data = evento.start._d;
    var dataString = data.getFullYear() + '-' + data.getMonth() + '-' + data.getDate();
    if(dias.indexOf(dataString) < 0){
        dias.push(dataString);
    }
});
```